# Auto select first option on dependent data validation dropdown in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I’m using a dependent drop down for users to select one option and then select a second option depending on their first choice. I'm doing this using a Filter function on a separate tab as range for the dependent list.

**I’m trying to figure out a way to auto select the first option of the dependent dropdown (in other words, to set a default value) when the main dropdown is changed.**

I have found scripts for clearing out the second dropdown, but not to select one of the available options. I'm a novice when it comes to writing code and I can’t find an answer on the internet.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share with us a copy of the script you used for clearing out the second dropdown?

Comment: Share a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.